# Can I replace the loop with just one DB connection?

Tags: java, mysql

today I have a problem.

it is just a simple query. But it needs multiple DB connection. So I used For loop like this. It works very slow. I want to improve the speed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < studentlist.size(); i++){
     StudentVO studentVO = new StudentVO(); 
     studentVO = studentDAO.getStudentData(stnum); // it connects with the query below
}
```

```
SELECT AMOUNT, STATUS, CONTENTS // SQL Query
        FROM RESULT
        WHERE STNUM = #{stnum}
```

This is my code

Is there any better way?

Comment: What is `studentlist`? Is it all students from the table? Or just a selection of specific users? If it's the former, then you could just drop that `WHERE` clause from your query and fetch all `Student` s with their data

Comment: @Lino I'm so sorry. I put wrong things. Studentlist is stnumList and stnum will be stnumList(i).

Comment: If the student list isn't too large you could use an IN clause in the WHERE and get them all at once. If the student list is large, it depends where you got it from. If from another query then use a JOIN, if from a condition the can be expressed in the WHERE clause then use it, otherwise put in the WHERE some condition that is inclusive of the desired students and get them all at once and filter them in the code.

Comment: Where does `stnum` come from?  What is `result`?  Try to never have a `SELECT` _inside_ a loop.  The database loves to grab lots of rows in a single query.